# cocoapods installed but import wont work

Tags: swift, websocket, socket.io, cocoapods

I am currently working on some Swift project's that require cocoapods installed. In a previous project I managed to install the pod file I need and worked fine but when I create a new to do some more tests the import statement doesn't seem to work even though I am working from the workspace and I can see the pod files in my project. I have done nothing different in this project than before but I still seem to be getting the same issues.

The pod I am using is socketio/socket.io-client-swift

but I have tried others and now it appears that no pods are worked at all on new projects and only on projects I have previously created

Comment: We are sorry to hear that.  Do you have any useful piece of information?

Comment: Try building your project using CMD+B and and also clean it then see if the import error goes away and if that doesn't work the last solution I have is to dry delete your derived data and build again

Answer (score 1):

Can you look into your directory in Finder and make sure the path is correct? Also, clean & rebuild your project.

What are the errors that Xcode encounters?